# Python lightblue : "AttributeError: module 'lightblue' has no attribute 'finddevices'"

Tags: python

.

Hi everyone, hope you're doing well!

I am trying to write a Python (3.8.9) script so that my computer detects every Bluetooth device it can find and provides me with the list of devices it has found.
Then, I installed `pybluez` and `lightblue` with

> pip3 install pybluez

and

> pip3 install python-lightblue

`python-lightblue` has the version 1.0.3.
Now, here's my code :

```
import bluetooth

def scan():
    print("Scanning for bluetooth devices:")
    devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, lookup_class = True)
    number_of_devices = len(devices)
    print(number_of_devices," devices found")
    for addr, name, device_class in devices:
        print("\n")
        print("Device:")
        print("Device Name: %s" % (name))
```

When I run this, I get the following mistake :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluetooth_detect.py", line 16, in <module>
    scan()
  File "bluetooth_detect.py", line 5, in scan
    devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, lookup_class = True)
  File "/Users/<my_name>/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/bluetooth/macos.py", line 12, in discover_devices
    devices = lightblue.finddevices(getnames=lookup_names, length=duration)
AttributeError: module 'lightblue' has no attribute 'finddevices'
```

Yet, when I check the documentation on the Internet, the module `lightblue` does have the attribute `finddevices`, and I can't find any mention of this problem on another forum (maybe I didn't look up long enough ?)

Would anyone have any idea ?
Thank you in advance ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in 3-year old latest version in pip registry.
Try to install from master from GitHub

> pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git

This will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I'm not working on this anymore, but it turns out it was only creating problems on MacOS, but not on Linux or Windows